# Vuejs - Two way binding with typescipt model classes

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to setup a new VueJs App basing on an existing Typescript-class structure with typescript model-classes. How do I need to integrate my models that the vuejs two-way-binding can work with them (recognize updates on the model)?

I tried to import the model class "person" and set them as class variable.

```
<template>
    <form>
        <input type="text" v-model="person.name" />
        {{person.name}}
    </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Person} from '@/models/person';
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import {Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({})
    export default class Home extends Vue{
        public person! : Person;

        created(){
            this.person = new Person();
        }
    }
</script>


--- Following person.ts:

export class Person{
    public name : string;
    public birthday: Date;
}
```

My expectation is that changing the input field for "name" the '{{name}}' also changes... 
Currently only calling this.$forceUpdate(); does the trick :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how you're defining `person`. The `!` in: `public person! : Person;`
is the non-null assertion operator, which means that variable will never be `null` or `undefined`.

Since you aren't assigning it a value in that expression though, you are basically writing:

`public person!: Person = undefined;`

---

I believe if you remove the created function and just did:

`public person: Person = new Person();`, it would work as you expect it to.

---

#### Edit

Since `person` is a prop, you need to pass in an already instantiated `Person` object from the parent which implements your component.

Your parent component would need to look something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <home :person="person"></home>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Home from "@/components/home";
import Person from "@/models/person";

@Component({})
export default class Parent extends Vue {
  private person: Person = new Person();
}
</script>
```

Then the child (the `Home` component in your example) would use it like this:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <input type="text" v-model="person.name" />
        {{person.name}}
    </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Person} from '@/models/person';
    import {Vue, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({})
    export default class Home extends Vue {
        @Prop()
        public person!: Person;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: great. Many thanks. This was exactly the issue. One additional question: In my solution the person is the Prop and I always get the error 'Avoid mutating a prop directly' because of the anti-pattern. Do you have a hint how to avoid that?

Comment: @SNO Well this would actually change to something closer to what you had before if `person` is a prop. Just to make sure, you have a parent component which implements the component in your example, and passes down a `Person` object, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly: @Prop() person : Person = new Person();

Comment: @SNO made an edit with (roughly) what you need. A prop needs to come from a parent and can't be created in the child component you're in. Hopefully that explains it to you

Comment: great. Excepting that I still get the error with the "Avoid mutating a prop..." this is exactly what I needed. Many thanks